# Is There a Shorter Way to Write This LINQ Construct?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to determine if a user is *only* a Salesperson. I have the following in my ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index() {
        string salespersonCode = null;

        var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
        if(roles.Count() == 1 && roles.Contains(UserRoles.Salesperson.ToString()))
            salespersonCode = User.Name();

        return View(new ProspectIndexViewModel { Prospects = _crmService.GetActiveProspects(salespersonCode) });
    }
```

Users may have more than one role. I want to limit the data returned to only that belonging to a salesperson if the user only has that role. The other three roles (Manager, Admin, and SalesAdministrator) shall receive the entire list. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer `roles.Count==0 && roles[0]=="Salesperson"` is laudably readable. Take care

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) method.

```
if(roles.All(r => r == UserRoles.Salesperson.ToString()))
```

But I see no problem with your code...

Comment: if roles = (for example) {"admin", "admin"}, then this code returns a false positive.

Comment: It works. Also, thanks for teaching me All(). I was only familiar w/ Any(). stackoverflow #ftw!

Answer (score 0):

```
var roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
if(!roles.Any(r => r != UserRoles.Salesperson.ToString()))
    salespersonCode = User.Name();
```

Comment: That code is not equivalent to what is being asked. It would pass if the user is both a Salesperson as well as some other role.

Comment: @driis, I don't agree. If the user is anything which is not a salesperson, it will not pass... But, that's true, we lack a roles.Any() && to be sure the user is anyhting

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
if (Page.User.IsInRole("Salesperson")) { ... };
```

Comment: That doesn't work because it'll ring true if the user is an Admin _and_ a Salesperson.